# Using @inlineCallbacks in Twisted trial unit tests

Tags: python, twisted, deferred, trial

I have some trial unit tests. In my code base some methods return deferreds with callbacks added while others are decorated with @inlineCallbacks. I want to run the test without a reactor, as some of the methods don't do any I/O. I tought @inlineCallbacks just returns a deferred, so calling callbacks(0) to fire it would be enough. It seems not the case. Here is a minimal example:

```
from twisted.trial import unittest
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks, returnValue, Deferred


def addone(val):
    d = Deferred()
    def cbk(res):
        return val + 1
    d.addCallback(cbk)
    return d


@inlineCallbacks
def call_addone(val):
    res = yield addone(val)
    returnValue(res)


class Tester(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_addone(self):
        d = addone(2)
        d.callback(0)   # whatever I pass is ignored
        self.assertEqual(3, self.successResultOf(d))

    def test_call_addone(self):
        d = call_addone(4)
        d.callback(0)   # whatever I pass is set as deferred's result
        self.assertEqual(5, self.successResultOf(d))
```

When I call addone(2) I get back a deferred that will return 2+1 when I fire it with callback(0). In this case the value passed to callback is ignored.
In the second test call_addone(4) returns a deferred too. But in this case the parameter passed to it is ignored, instead the return value will be whatever I pass to callback(). Why? I am clearly missing something.

Here is the output of trial runner:

```
test_trial
  Tester
    test_addone ...                                                        [OK]
    test_call_addone ...                                                 [FAIL]

===============================================================================
[FAIL]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/test_trial.py", line 31, in test_call_addone
    self.assertEqual(5, self.successResultOf(d))
  File "/home/b/.local/share/virtualenvs/twproba-y019OThE/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/trial/_synctest.py", line 432, in assertEqual
    super(_Assertions, self).assertEqual(first, second, msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/case.py", line 821, in assertEqual
    assertion_func(first, second, msg=msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/case.py", line 814, in _baseAssertEqual
    raise self.failureException(msg)
twisted.trial.unittest.FailTest: 5 != 0

test_trial.Tester.test_call_addone
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.029s

FAILED (failures=1, successes=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines are pretty much wrong (given that `call_addone` is defined with `inlineCallbacks`):

```
    d = call_addone(4)
    d.callback(0)   # whatever I pass is set as deferred's result
```

This goes along with these lines being weird (given that `inlineCallbacks` is not used):

```
    d = addone(2)
    d.callback(0)   # whatever I pass is ignored
```

In both cases, you are asking some library code to create a `Deferred` and then your application code is supplying a result for the `Deferred`.  Since `addone` does what you want, clearly it's *possible* to use `Deferred` this way.  However, it's not a good practice.  Best practice is for the responsibility for *creating* and *firing* a `Deferred` to lie in the same place.  So, in this case, with the implementation of `addone`.

The reason your failing test fails is that you've not accounted for the implementation of `inlineCallbacks` which believes that it is indeed responsible for firing the `Deferred` it returns.  And the `Deferred` it returns is *not* the `Deferred` returned by the `addone` call it makes.  It keeps that `Deferred` to itself.

The result of `d` in:

```
    d = call_addone(4)
    d.callback(0)   # whatever I pass is set as deferred's result
```

is `0` precisely because you've supplied a result of 0.  You've supplied the result to the `inlineCallbacks`-managed `Deferred` and short-circuited all of the rest of the implementation of `inlineCallbacks`.  If the `Deferred` returned by `addone` did ever fire, you would likely see an `AlreadyCalledError` because `inlineCallbacks` would try to supply a result to `d`, the `Deferred` you already supplied a result to.

Comment: So in short: before I return a _new_ deferred it should be fired. No need to fire the deferred if I got it from somewhere else (maybe adbapi or a inlineCallback)?

Comment: You can return it before it is fired - in fact, that is the primary usefulness of Deferred.  But the code that fires it should be logically part of the same "unit" as the code that created it.  It's kind of a fuzzy idea.  I don't know of a hard and fast rule that applies to all situations to tell you whether the right code is doing the firing...  Well, one good rule is that if the API documentation doesn't _tell you_ you have to fire the Deferred, you shouldn't fire it.  But that doesn't help much most of the time.